# Nested SQL case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-statement

I'm trying to bucket unit statuses. What am I doing wrong with my case statement? I'm new to SQL.

```
CASE WHEN [sStatus] LIKE '%Notice%'
                THEN 'Notice'
            ELSE 
                CASE WHEN [sStatus] LIKE '%Occupied%'
                        THEN 'Occupied'
                    ELSE 
                        CASE WHEN [sStatus] LIKE '%Vacant%'
                                THEN 'Vacant'
                            ELSE [sStatus]
        END as [Status]
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Error is: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case statements are missing ends.  But, they don't need to be nested in the first place:

```
(CASE WHEN [sStatus] LIKE '%Notice%' THEN 'Notice'
      WHEN [sStatus] LIKE '%Occupied%' THEN 'Occupied'
      WHEN [sStatus] LIKE '%Vacant%' THEN 'Vacant'
      ELSE [sStatus]
 END) as [Status]
```

And, if you just want the first word, you don't need a `case` at all:

```
SUBSTRING(sStatus, CHARINDEX(' ', sStatus + ' '), LEN(sStatus))
```

Comment: Didn't know I could use WHEN multiple times like that! Thank you!

Comment: Would it be more operationally efficient to use substring?

Comment: @Walker . . . It might be slightly more efficient.  I think `substring()` is faster than `like` with a wildcard at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you have 3 CASE statements and only one END.

However, there is no need to nest these CASE statements at all.   You can simply do this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN [sStatus] LIKE '%Notice%'
                THEN 'Notice'
  WHEN [sStatus] LIKE '%Occupied%'
                THEN 'Occupied'
  WHEN [sStatus] LIKE '%Vacant%'
                THEN 'Vacant'
  ELSE [sStatus]      
END as [Status]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN [sStatus] LIKE '%Notice%' THEN 'Notice'
     WHEN [sStatus] LIKE '%Occupied%' THEN 'Occupied'
     WHEN [sStatus] LIKE '%Vacant%' THEN 'Vacant'
     ELSE [sStatus] END as Status
```

You don't need all those else